# Custom username paths?

Tags: 8, routes

I want to be able to create paths like this:

```
/guy1
/guy2
/guy3
```

It's easy enough if I want /profile/guy1 ... then I can just do this:

```
gg_profile.viewUserProfile:
  path: '/profile/{username}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\gg_profile\Controller\GGProfileController::viewUserProfile'
```

But I want it to work with the /profile bit. Changing it as follows doesn't work:

```
  path: '/{username}'
```

How do I make it work without having the extra /profile bit?

Comment: Perhaps you should create routes specific to your module, so that they would use a unique pattern. Then in your module you could suggest desired route as a Pathauto pattern. So, `/guy1` would be an alias to your route.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot: The part of the path after the first slash cannot be dynamic, so you cannot use /{username} as path. This is explicitly stated in [Structure of routes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643), which describes *path* as follows.

> **path (required):** The URL to the route, *with a leading forward slash* (e.g., `path: '/book'`). You can use dynamic properties by including them in curly braces. (e.g., `path: '/node/{node}/outline'`). These will be passed along as arguments via *parameter converters* to the controller/form (see below). Note that the first item of the path must not be dynamic.

You can use /profile/{username}, but /{username} doesn't work.

Comment: So to do this, I would need to not use Drupal? That sucks...

Comment: You could implement the equivalent of Drupal 7 `hook_url_inbound_alter()` but be careful of what you would alter, which means any route defined from other modules still have to work properly.

Comment: That is why a path like /{username} would not work. Drupal would not be able to understand if node in /node/1 is a username, or user in /user/1 is a username.

Comment: I get that, but I thought i could have custom logic and basically tell it to skip my logic if a certain condition is not met.

Comment: For that, you should alter the way Drupal checks for routes, if it is possible. By default, Drupal doesn't have an _apply my logic if some conditions are met_ mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the Pathauto Module could come in handy for this.  https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto

Your use case is kind of vague so I don't know exactly what you want but you can use Pathauto to create 'dynamic' URL endpoints when creating new content/users.  You can use tokens within the URL to add variables.

Comment: I would have to use nodes if I want to do this. Which is probably what I'm going to end up doing anyway.

Comment: Pathauto supports any entity type but it looks like that is some special thing. The same still applies. You can't have top-level routes like that, but you can have aliases, you just have to create them yourself then